# Verify a two-form is calibration

Tags: differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry, minimal-surfaces, calibrated-geometry

$u: \Omega \subset \mathbb R^2 \rightarrow \mathbb R$ is a $C^2$ function. Graph of $u$ is 
$$
G_u=\{(x,y,u(x,y)) : (x,y)\in \Omega\}
$$
And the upward pointing unit normal is $N$. $\omega$ is the two-form on $\Omega\times \mathbb R$ given by that for $X,Y\in \mathbb R^3$
$$
\omega(X,Y) = \det (X,Y,N)
$$
Then we have 
$$
\omega(\partial_x, \partial_y) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{1+|\nabla u|^2}}  \\
\omega(\partial_y, \partial_z) = \frac{-u_x}{\sqrt{1+|\nabla u|^2}}  \\
\omega(\partial_x, \partial_z) = \frac{u_y}{\sqrt{1+|\nabla u|^2}}
$$
$\partial_x, \partial_y, \partial_z$ are the standard basis of $\mathbb R^3$. Then, **how to show given any orthogonal unit vectors $X,Y$ at a point $(x,y,z)$ we have 
$$
|\omega(X,Y)|\le 1
$$
And equality holds iff
$$
X,Y\subset T_{(x,y,u(x,y))} G_u
$$**

This question is from 1.1 of T.H. Colding and W.P. Minicozzi's Minimal surfaces.

Comment: Use $\omega(X,Y) = \det(X,Y,N) = (X \times Y) \cdot N$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This supposed to be obvious, because $\det(X,Y,N)$ is the volume of the parallelepiped formed by vectors $X$, $Y$, and $N$. Vectors $X$ are $Y$ orthogonal, and if they lie in the tangent plane, the parallelepiped is a unit cube. For the converse you need to use a [formula](http://mathinsight.org/scalar_triple_product) for the triple product, or the fact that the cube has the maximal volume among all parallelepipeds with equal sides.